# fopen / fputcsv in PHP returns true but doesn't write

Tags: php, csv, fopen, fputcsv

I simply need to write a line to a csv:

```
//write entery to csv
$file = fopen("valentines.csv","a+");

//values
$values = array(
    $queryParams['firstName'],
    $queryParams['lastName'],
    $queryParams['email'],
    $queryParams['valentine'],
    $queryParams['message']
);

$writeCsv = fputcsv($file,$values);

fclose($file);

return array('success'=>true,'fopen'=>$file,'fputcsv'=>$writeCsv,'exists'=>file_exists("valentines.csv"),'readable'=>is_readable("valentines.csv"),'writeable'=>is_writeable("valentines.csv"));
```

The return is simply for debugging right now. Here is what's returned:

```
exists:true
fopen:null
fputcsv:91
readable:true
success:true
writeable:true
```

When I check the file there's only one line in there, the one I added manually to the headers when importing.

Comment: The location of valentines.csv might not be correct. Try using absolute path

Comment: Maybe `$values` is empty?

Comment: `fopen:null` - file is not opened correctly

Comment: Working perfectly for me .. Check $query params

Comment: The code looks good! I think it is a permission problem with the folder you want to write to, since "a+" creates files, if they do not exist. Also check, if you are checking the correct file. Currently you are writing to the folder, the PHP file is located in.

Comment: @kawadhiya21 trying that returns `fopen` as false. The php file that writes to the file is already in the same directory.

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI Checked those and their fine

Comment: Once you are done executing the script, check if `valentines.csv` is created somewhere else, may be in current folder or from where the script is getting executed.

If fopen is returning false, then there is permissions issue. It should be 0775

Comment: @kawadhiya21 great idea, everything writes to the root. I pointed `fopen` to `/home/www/mysite.com/theme/mytheme/valentines.csv` and that didn't work. 'fopen` returns false. It writes but only to the root...

Comment: You need to give access to user which executes the script. If it is run by webserver,  then the user is apache.